# What variable should I use if I want to save time values?

Tags: c#, .net, time

I want to make an app that adds 1 minutes and 25 seconds to a TimeLeft variable.

Problem is I have no idea what type of variable this should be, or even how to add 1 minutes 25 seconds to the available time left.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. I'm good with C#, but since I've never done something like, I'm in the dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) variable. This will let you manipulate the time. If you want to add 1m 25s to a varible, you could simply use:

```
DateTime newTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(85);
```

That will add 85 seconds onto the current time (or, in your case, `TimeLeft` as long as the TimeLeft variable is also a DateTime type)

Answer (score 3):

[`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) works well. It's specifically designed to hold a duration of time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DateTime type.  Assuming your TimeLeft variable is an integer, you probably need to convert it to DateTime type first and then perform the add.  More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)